what are the changes to be done in client yaml file?
How does the communication between two different pods happen in Kubernetes?
In my case I have two pods: frontend and backend, both have different containers. I want my frontend pod to communicate with the backend pod but I don't want to use backend pod's IP( i.e. hard coded).
Is it possible through services?
this is my client file
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: grpc-client-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: grpc-client-container
    image: rakeshreddypeddamallu512/grpc-client:v6
    command: ["./client"]  # Command to run the gRPC client

pod to pod communication

I guess just like you would in the non kubernetes world. Use host names instead of IP adresses. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Kubernetes have internal DNS, you should be able to access pods in the same namespace via the name of the services used for accessing the deployment.
like: 
Inside the pod.
ping client-service
# or with FQDN
ping client-service.namespace.svc.cluster.local

Assuming you want access from pod to pod, not from user browser to backend.
